# Not called surfaceCreated when add camera object in surface in new runOnUiThread

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview

Sorry for my english. I have `activity1`, and `activity2`. In `activity1` i have button, when i click this button this button freezes for a few seconds and after this open `activity2`. To remove a freeze when click button in `activity1` I added code that launches the camera in new `runOnUiThread` but now not called `surfaceCreated`.

**mPreview** - my custom surfaceView

**mCamera** - object camera

**My code:**

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        CameraActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mPreview.addCamera(mCamera);
                mPreview.addParent(CameraActivity.this);
                mCamera.getParameters().setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
                mPreview.refreshDrawableState();
                mCamera.startPreview();
            }
        });
    }
}).start();
```

My costom `SurfaceView` ( i add only important code)

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    public CameraPreview (Context context){
        super(context);
    }
    public CameraPreview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    public CameraPreview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public void addCamera(Camera camera){
            mCamera = camera;
            mHolder = getHolder();
            mHolder.addCallback(this);
            mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {

            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            if(mCamera!=null){
                mCamera.stopPreview();
                mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);

                mCamera.release();
                mCamera = null;
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(this.getContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
    //code
    mCamera.startPreview();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's the expected behaviour, the `Surface` is maintained by the `SurfaceView`, as a workaround you could check if the surface is valid and has non-0 dimentions and call your `surfaceCreated/surfaceChanged`functions manually

the code you need:

```
Surface surface = mHolder.getSurface();
if(surface != null && surface.isValid()){
    Rect frame = mHolder.getSurfaceFrame();
    if(frame.width() > 0 && frame.height() > 0){
         surfaceCreated(mHolder);
         surfaceChaged(mHolder, PixelFormat.OPAQUE, frame.width(), frame.height()); //pixel format OPAQUE is the default one
    }
}
```